# Can we bind the ManagedObject to View?

Tags: sapui5

I have prepared a object which by extending [ManagedObject](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html)

and I have added these into the JSONModel of the view in controller as

```
var model = new JSONModel({
    data : someOne.getManagedObjects()
});
```

How to bind these to view? I have tried these

1: `<List id="mainLayerList"
                    selectionChange="onSelectionChange" 
                    mode = "MultiSelect"
                    items="{/data}">`

2:

```
<List id="mainLayerList"
                    selectionChange="onSelectionChange" 
                    mode = "MultiSelect"
                    items="{
                    path: '/data',
                    factory: '.dataListItemFactory'
                }">
```

Not getting the data on view.

Can we bind the ManagedObject to the view?

Comment: I am trying with employee data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to any Javascript object. But you can only use attributes and properties on the bound objects. So you can't call functions like `getName()`.

What do ManagedObjects do with the properties you declared in the metadata? It creates `getXxx()` and `setXxx()` methods and stores the data *xxx* somewhere inside a private object. Thats why you cant bind to `{xxx}` even though you have declared a *xxx* property on the ManagedObject.

As a workaround you could create [getter properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) on your ManagedObject for all attributes you want to bind to:

```
get xxx()  { return this.getXxx();} 
set xxx(value) { this.setXxx(value);}
```